# Android UI Button Alpha Property

Tags: android, android-layout

If I change the Alpha setting on a Button widget to make it translucent, then add a background image to the Button, will the image also be translucent?

Comment: If your background is covering up your entire button and your are worried about its transparency then, why are you changing the alpha property. Do you have an example.

Comment: No, not yet. Barely started on this app and don't have all the images made.

Comment: I'm having trouble realizing how your button will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Changing the background property will override any of the styling you have applied to the button and use only that. So if you use a Material-style button that has custom colors, then apply a background property, the "button" will disappear and be only a perfect rectangle of whatever color (including alpha) that you set, with text/drawables on top.